# WinSCP error "No such file" when uploading files to server

Tags: vb.net, ssh, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

Currently I'm programmatically trying to upload files to a server using the WinSCP API.

However looking at the log files every time I attempt to do this I get an error stating that the remote file or it's directory doesn't exist.

**Code:**

```
Dim objftp As New WinSCP.SessionOptions
objftp.HostName = Server
objftp.PortNumber = Port
objftp.Protocol = Protocol.Sftp
objftp.UserName = User
objftp.Password = Password
objftp.PrivateKeyPassphrase = "passPhrase"
objftp.SshPrivateKeyPath = "\\PathToPrivatekey.ppk"
objftp.GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = True

Dim session As New Session

session.Timeout = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
session.SessionLogPath = "C:\Temp\ftpLog\winscp.log"
session.Open(objFTP)

Dim transferOptions As New TransferOptions

transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary
transferOptions.ResumeSupport.State = TransferResumeSupportState.Off
Dim transferResult As TransferOperationResult

strLocalFile = FilePath & FileName
strRemoteFile = FileName
transferResult = session.PutFiles(strLocalFile, "/In/", False, transferOptions)

transferResult.Check()

session.Close()
```

Now I have manually using WinSCP connected to the server and I can verify that the `/In/` directory does exist.  I am using a Windows OS to do this.  I don't have full details on the server I'm connecting to as it's a third party I'm sending information to.

Is there something I'm missing in my code?

EDIT: As requested this is my logs:

Log from programmatically trying it:

```
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.089 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.089 WinSCP Version 5.9.3 (Build 7136) (OS 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 - Windows 7 Professional)
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.089 Configuration: nul
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.089 Log level: Normal
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.089 Local account: user\Andrew
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.089 Working directory: \\WorkingDIr\
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.089 Process ID: 12648
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.090 Command-line: "\\WorkingDir\winscp.exe" /xmllog="C:\Users\andrew\AppData\Local\Temp\wscp46E9.02B7AFA0.tmp" /xmlgroups /xmllogrequired /nointeractiveinput /dotnet=593  /ini=nul /log="C:\Temp\ftpLog\winscp.log"  /console /consoleinstance=_10192_57352375_875
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.090 Time zone: Current: GMT+0, Standard: GMT+0 (GMT Standard Time), DST: GMT+1 (GMT Daylight Time), DST Start: 27/03/2016, DST End: 30/10/2016
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.090 Login time: 23 December 2016 10:52:07
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.090 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.094 Script: Retrospectively logging previous script records:
> 2016-12-23 10:52:07.094 Script: option batch on
< 2016-12-23 10:52:07.094 Script: batch           on        
< 2016-12-23 10:52:07.094 Script: reconnecttime   120       
> 2016-12-23 10:52:07.094 Script: option confirm off
< 2016-12-23 10:52:07.094 Script: confirm         off       
> 2016-12-23 10:52:07.094 Script: option reconnecttime 120
< 2016-12-23 10:52:07.094 Script: reconnecttime   120       
> 2016-12-23 10:52:07.094 Script: open sftp://user:***@server.com:22 -hostkey="*" -privatekey="\\containingDir\PrivateKey.ppk" -passphrase=*** -timeout=15
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.094 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.094 Session name: user@server.com (Ad-Hoc site)
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.094 Host name: server.com (Port: 22)
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 User name: user(Password: Yes, Key file: Yes, Passphrase: Yes)
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 Tunnel: No
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 Transfer Protocol: SFTP
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 Ping type: Off, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 Disable Nagle: No
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 Proxy: None
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 Send buffer: 262144
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 SSH protocol version: 2; Compression: No
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 Bypass authentication: No
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 Try agent: Yes; Agent forwarding: No; TIS/CryptoCard: No; KI: Yes; GSSAPI: No
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 Ciphers: aes,chacha20,blowfish,3des,WARN,arcfour,des; Ssh2DES: No
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 KEX: ecdh,dh-gex-sha1,dh-group14-sha1,rsa,WARN,dh-group1-sha1
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 SSH Bugs: Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 Simple channel: Yes
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 Return code variable: Autodetect; Lookup user groups: Auto
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 Shell: default
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 EOL: LF, UTF: Auto
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 Clear aliases: Yes, Unset nat.vars: Yes, Resolve symlinks: Yes; Follow directory symlinks: No
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 LS: ls -la, Ign LS warn: Yes, Scp1 Comp: No
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 SFTP Bugs: Auto,Auto
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 SFTP Server: default
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 Local directory: default, Remote directory: home, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 Recycle bin: Delete to: No, Overwritten to: No, Bin path: 
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 DST mode: Unix
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.095 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.106 Looking up host "server.com" for SSH connection
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.126 Connecting to 11.11.11.11 port 22
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.307 We claim version: SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_5.9.3
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.496 Server version: SSH-2.0-9.99 sshlib: 8.1.0.0
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.496 We believe remote version has SSH-2 channel request bug
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.496 Using SSH protocol version 2
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.504 Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
. 2016-12-23 10:52:07.928 Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-1
. 2016-12-23 10:52:08.307 Host key fingerprint is:
. 2016-12-23 10:52:08.307 ssh-rsa fingerprint
. 2016-12-23 10:52:08.308 Verifying host key host key
* 2016-12-23 10:52:08.308 WARNING! Giving up security and accepting any host key as configured!
. 2016-12-23 10:52:08.310 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
. 2016-12-23 10:52:08.310 Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
. 2016-12-23 10:52:08.310 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
. 2016-12-23 10:52:08.310 Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
. 2016-12-23 10:52:08.741 Reading key file "\\PrivateKseyDir\PrivateKey.ppk"
. 2016-12-23 10:52:08.764 Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
. 2016-12-23 10:52:08.766 Pageant has 0 SSH-2 keys
. 2016-12-23 10:52:08.766 Configured key file not in Pageant
! 2016-12-23 10:52:08.766 Using username "user".
. 2016-12-23 10:52:08.958 Server offered these authentication methods: publickey,password
. 2016-12-23 10:52:08.958 Offered public key
. 2016-12-23 10:52:09.193 Offer of public key accepted
! 2016-12-23 10:52:09.193 Authenticating with public key "rsa-key-20161222"
. 2016-12-23 10:52:09.194 Prompt (passphrase, "SSH key passphrase", <no instructions>, "Passphrase for key "rsa-key-20161222": ")
. 2016-12-23 10:52:09.194 Using configured passphrase.
. 2016-12-23 10:52:09.316 Sent public key signature
! 2016-12-23 10:52:09.504 Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key!
. 2016-12-23 10:52:09.504 Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key!
. 2016-12-23 10:52:09.504 Server offered these authentication methods: password
. 2016-12-23 10:52:09.504 Prompt (password, "SSH password", <no instructions>, "&Password: ")
. 2016-12-23 10:52:09.504 Using stored password.
. 2016-12-23 10:52:09.505 Sent password
. 2016-12-23 10:52:09.831 Access granted
. 2016-12-23 10:52:09.831 Opening session as main channel
. 2016-12-23 10:52:10.017 Opened main channel
. 2016-12-23 10:52:10.426 Started a shell/command
. 2016-12-23 10:52:10.426 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2016-12-23 10:52:10.432 Using SFTP protocol.
. 2016-12-23 10:52:10.432 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2016-12-23 10:52:10.441 Type: SSH_FXP_INIT, Size: 5, Number: -1
< 2016-12-23 10:52:10.631 Type: SSH_FXP_VERSION, Size: 5, Number: -1
. 2016-12-23 10:52:10.631 SFTP version 3 negotiated.
. 2016-12-23 10:52:10.631 We believe the server has signed timestamps bug
. 2016-12-23 10:52:10.631 We will use UTF-8 strings until server sends an invalid UTF-8 string as with SFTP version 3 and older UTF-8 strings are not mandatory
. 2016-12-23 10:52:10.635 Getting current directory name.
. 2016-12-23 10:52:10.639 Getting real path for '.'
> 2016-12-23 10:52:10.639 Type: SSH_FXP_REALPATH, Size: 10, Number: 16
< 2016-12-23 10:52:10.825 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 43, Number: 16
. 2016-12-23 10:52:10.825 Real path is '/Home/user'
. 2016-12-23 10:52:10.825 Startup conversation with host finished.
< 2016-12-23 10:52:10.826 Script: Active session: [1] server.com
> 2016-12-23 10:52:11.141 Script: pwd
< 2016-12-23 10:52:11.141 Script: /Home/user
> 2016-12-23 10:52:26.491 Script: put  -nopermissions -preservetime -transfer="binary" -resumesupport="off" -- "\\fileDir\testFile.dat" "/In/testFile.dat"
. 2016-12-23 10:52:26.497 Copying 1 files/directories to remote directory "/In/"
. 2016-12-23 10:52:26.497   PrTime: Yes; PrRO: No; Rght: rw-r--r--; PrR: No (No); FnCs: N; RIC: 0100; Resume: N (102400); CalcS: No; Mask: testFile.dat
. 2016-12-23 10:52:26.497   TM: B; ClAr: No; RemEOF: No; RemBOM: No; CPS: 0; NewerOnly: No; InclM: ; ResumeL: 0
. 2016-12-23 10:52:26.497   AscM: *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h; *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml
. 2016-12-23 10:52:26.502 File: '\\fileDir\testFile.dat' [2016-12-23T06:31:02.639Z] [212952]
. 2016-12-23 10:52:26.504 Copying "\\fileDir\testFile.dat" to remote directory started.
. 2016-12-23 10:52:26.504 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2016-12-23 10:52:26.505 Opening remote file.
> 2016-12-23 10:52:26.509 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 50, Number: 259
< 2016-12-23 10:52:26.681 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 31, Number: 259
< 2016-12-23 10:52:26.681 Status code: 2, Message: 259, Server: No such file, Language: en 
> 2016-12-23 10:52:26.681 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 34, Number: 519
< 2016-12-23 10:52:26.849 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 31, Number: 519
< 2016-12-23 10:52:26.849 Status code: 2, Message: 519, Server: No such file, Language: en 
* 2016-12-23 10:52:26.849 (ETerminal) No such file or directory.
* 2016-12-23 10:52:26.849 Error code: 2
* 2016-12-23 10:52:26.849 Error message from server (en): No such file
. 2016-12-23 10:52:26.850 Asking user:
. 2016-12-23 10:52:26.850 Cannot create remote file '/In/testFile.dat'. ("No such file or directory.
. 2016-12-23 10:52:26.850 Error code: 2
. 2016-12-23 10:52:26.850 Error message from server (en): No such file")
< 2016-12-23 10:52:26.850 Script: Cannot create remote file '/In/testFile.dat'.
< 2016-12-23 10:52:26.850 Script: No such file or directory.
< 2016-12-23 10:52:26.850 Error code: 2
< 2016-12-23 10:52:26.850 Error message from server (en): No such file
* 2016-12-23 10:52:26.862 (EScpSkipFile) Cannot create remote file '/In/testFile.dat'.
* 2016-12-23 10:52:26.862 No such file or directory.
* 2016-12-23 10:52:26.862 Error code: 2
* 2016-12-23 10:52:26.862 Error message from server (en): No such file
. 2016-12-23 10:52:26.862 Script: Failed
```

And this is the log from me doing it successfully with the GUI:

```
> 2016-12-23 10:59:12.037 Type: SSH_FXP_SETSTAT, Size: 54, Number: 2057
< 2016-12-23 10:59:12.221 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 40, Number: 2057
< 2016-12-23 10:59:12.221 Status code: 8, Message: 2057, Server: Operation unsupported, Language: en 
* 2016-12-23 10:59:12.222 (ETerminal) The server does not support the operation.
* 2016-12-23 10:59:12.222 Error code: 8
* 2016-12-23 10:59:12.222 Error message from server (en): Operation unsupported
. 2016-12-23 10:59:12.226 Asking user:
. 2016-12-23 10:59:12.226 **Upload of file 'sftpTest.dat' was successful, but error occurred while setting the permissions and/or timestamp.**
. 2016-12-23 10:59:12.226 
. 2016-12-23 10:59:12.226 If the problem persists, turn off setting permissions or preserving timestamp. Alternatively you can turn on 'Ignore permission errors' option. ("The server does not support the operation.
. 2016-12-23 10:59:12.226 Error code: 8
. 2016-12-23 10:59:12.226 Error message from server (en): Operation unsupported")
* 2016-12-23 10:59:14.385 (EScpSkipFile) **Upload of file 'sftpTest.dat' was successful, but error occurred while setting the permissions and/or timestamp.**
* 2016-12-23 10:59:14.385 
* 2016-12-23 10:59:14.385 If the problem persists, turn off setting permissions or preserving timestamp. Alternatively you can turn on 'Ignore permission errors' option.
* 2016-12-23 10:59:14.385 The server does not support the operation.
* 2016-12-23 10:59:14.385 Error code: 8
* 2016-12-23 10:59:14.385 Error message from server (en): Operation unsupported
. 2016-12-23 10:59:14.386 Listing directory "/Home/user".
> 2016-12-23 10:59:14.386 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 20, Number: 4875
< 2016-12-23 10:59:14.602 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 13, Number: 4875
> 2016-12-23 10:59:14.603 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 13, Number: 5132
< 2016-12-23 10:59:14.817 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 245, Number: 5132
> 2016-12-23 10:59:14.817 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 13, Number: 5388
< 2016-12-23 10:59:15.022 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 30, Number: 5388
< 2016-12-23 10:59:15.022 Status code: 1
> 2016-12-23 10:59:15.022 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 13, Number: 5636
. 2016-12-23 10:59:15.022 In;d;0;2016-12-20T15:48:00.000Z;"0" [0];"0" [0];rwxrwxrwx;1
. 2016-12-23 10:59:15.022 sftpTest.dat;-;212952;2016-12-23T10:59:00.000Z;"0" [0];"0" [0];rw-rw-rw-;1
```

Comment: Show us an exact error message, or even better the log file. + Show us a WinSCP GUI log file showing how you (successfully) upload the same file to the same remote directory.

Comment: Added the logging there

Comment: Please post a complete log. This does not help at all.

Comment: Apologies I've just posted a complete log from the programmatically performed version.

Comment: But we need also a complete GUI log. Though, see my preliminary answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I cannot tell for sure, as you didn't provide enough information, my guess is that your real target path should be like `/Home/user/In/`, not just `/In/`.

From the GUI log, it seems that your account is not chrooted, as the home directory is `/Home/user/`, not `/`.

```
. 2016-12-23 10:59:14.386 Listing directory "/Home/user".
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  This was the issue.  Hope you have a good holiday period!!

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_putfiles) talks about the full path to the remote file, not the directory with the file. You can try to specify full path:

```
transferResult = session.PutFiles(strLocalFile, "/In/remote_file.ext", False, transferOptions)
```

Comment: I did give that a try but unfortunately that's returning the same issue.

Comment: I have got logging and it's returning the following:
< 2016-12-23 10:52:26.849 Status code: 2, Message: 519, Server: No such file, Language: en 
* 2016-12-23 10:52:26.849 (ETerminal) No such file or directory.
* 2016-12-23 10:52:26.849 Error code: 2
* 2016-12-23 10:52:26.849 Error message from server (en): No such file
. 2016-12-23 10:52:26.850 Asking user:
. 2016-12-23 10:52:26.850 Cannot create remote file '/In/sftpTest.dat'. ("No such file or directory.